# finding duplications in arrays

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

i am very fresh with C. Currently I am writing a program which should display duplicates in array. Program reads (from user), N numbers (but N < 100), and after that display numbers which are duplicated. 
My code work, but i have problem with display. 
For example, when it is 5 elenets array numb[5] = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, program display 2 three times, and it should display 2 one time.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
    int main () 
    {
        int n, i, j, numbers[100]={0};
        printf("number of elements (max 100):");
        scanf("%i", &n);
        printf("enter elements:");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           for j = i+1; j < n; j++)
           {
               if (numbers[i] ==numbers[j])
               {
                  printf("duplicates:%i\n", numbers[i]);
               }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to keep track of which duplicates you've found already and not display them if they're in that list. *I have problem with display. For example,...* If you have any other issues, you need to be specific. People aren't going to review your code and try to find any other problems you may have. You need to do the work and ask a specific question.

Comment: this is only issue, this for example, is like "for example for this array, where some numbers are more than two times". But anyway thaks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `numbers[i] ==numbers[j]` true you need to either delete duplicates(shifting) or some other ways to not to print duplicates again. So write logic for that.

here is my edit in your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
        int n, i, j,k, numbers[100]={0};
        printf("number of elements (max 100):");
        scanf("%i", &n);
        printf("enter elements:");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                        if (numbers[j] ==numbers[j+1])//once true shift all elements by once 
                        {
                                for(k=j; k<n; k++)//loop for shifting elemenst
                                        numbers[k]=numbers[k+1];
                                j--;//again starts comparing from previous position
                                n--;// no of elements reduced 
                        }
                }
        }
        for(i=0; i<n ;i++)
                printf("%d \n",numbers[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.